How to automatically redirect without ".html" extension
I am attempting to set up a custom Zoom link as redirect from my website. Unfortunately, it seems I can only obtain a working redirect from an address ending in ".html".
Currently, my pelicanconf.py contains the following:
ARTICLE_EXCLUDES = [
    'static',
]

STATIC_PATHS = [
    'static',
]
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {
    'static/zoom.html': {'path': 'zoom.html'},
}


The page content/static/zoom.html contains the following:
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=https://zoom.com/j/5555555555">
 
<script>
  window.location.href = "https://zoom.com/j/5555555555"
</script>
 
<title>Page Redirection</title>
 
If you are not redirected automatically, follow <a href='https://zoom.com/j/5555555555'>this link</a>

This works, in the sense that visiting www.mysite.net/zoom.html my Zoom room opens. However, there is no way I can get it working for www.mysite.net/zoom, which would be the desired result.
Is there a way to do it?

Did you try renaming your file zoom.html to index.html and place it in a directory named zoom? Then your room should be accessible via www.mysite.net/zoom/. Access may also work without the trailing /, but it may then be added automatically depending on the configuration of your Webserver or the framework, you use.

as suggested by kzi change the filename to index.html OR use something like nginx to manage routing

@kzi That worked! Thank you!
